# Databound TreeView not updating after nodes have been expanded

Tags: wpf

I have set up a databound TreeView like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeGui" ItemsSource="{Binding tree.Folders}" Margin="5" SelectedItemChanged="TreeGui_SelectedItemChanged" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Foreground="{Binding ForeGround}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

If I start the task that does some work and updates the nodes accordingly, let it run to completion, I can expand the tree and see the correct headers.

If I expand the tree, before or during the task, any headers shown will not update anymore. Even though their data changes.

I'm quite new to C# and WPF, so there is probably something basic I am missing. Please help me see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Only the `tree` implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

I changed the individual items in `Folders` to also implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and send the proper events when `Header` and `ForeGround` is updated.

Thank you for your patience ;)